# Unterschied zwischen »tauschen« und »(aus)wechseln«

Tags: word-usage, difference, meaning-in-context

Worin besteht der Unterschied zwischen *tauschen* und *(aus)wechseln?*

**Anwendungsfall:**
Handlungsanweisungen in der Industrie.
Wann benutzt man *Bauteil (aus)wechseln,* wann *Bauteil tauschen?*

**Lösungsansatz:**
*(Aus)wechseln,* wenn das Bauteil defekt oder kaputt ist. Das neue Bauteil ist dabei baugleich.
*Tauschen,* wenn es die Funktion nicht oder schlechter erfüllt. Das neue Bauteil ist ein verbessertes, anderes Bauteil.

Ist mein Ansatz korrekt und wenn ja, welche Logik liegt dahinter?

Answer (score 4):

**Tauschen** ist primär eine Handlung zwischen Individuen, bei der ein Objekt aus der Hand von A, das für B einen bestimmten Wert hat, an B weitergegeben wird, während ein Objekt von B, das für A einen vergleichbaren Wert hat, an A weitergegeben wird (Tauschhandel).

Man tauscht etwas *gegen* etwas anderes bzw. etwas *für* etwas anderes *ein*.

**Auswechseln** ist eine Handlung, bei der ein Objekt an einem bestimmten Ort durch ein anderes Objekt (oft derselben Art) ersetzt wird.

*Tauschen* im Sinn von *auswechseln* hat sich vermutlich als Kurzform von *austauschen* als Synonym von *auswechseln* etabliert. Spezielle Bedeutungsnuancen kann ich hinsichtlich der Anwendung in unterschiedlichen Branchen oder auch der Komplexität (und des Wertes) der betroffenen Objekte ausmachen: eine defekte Dichtung wird ausgewechselt, eine Platine getauscht.

Answer (score 4):

`tauschen` und `wechseln` sind beides ziemlich allgemeine Verben, die man durch Präfixe präzisieren kann:

- `austauschen`
- `auswechseln`
- `vertauschen`
- `verwechseln`

Beide Verben drücken aus, dass ein Objekt die Rolle/den Platz/die Funktion eines anderen Objekts einnimmt und umgekehrt.

Das Präfix `aus-` drückt dabei aus, dass eines der Objekte keine Rolle/keinen Platz/keine Funktion hat.

Das Präfix `ver-` drückt aus, dass beide Objekte ähnliche/gleichrangige/gleichermaßen bedeutsame Rollen/Plätze/Funktionen haben, wobei `verwechseln` eine eigene Bedeutung entwickelt hat.

`austauschen` und `auswechseln` sind also im Allgemeinen synonym, wobei sie als Termini natürlich besondere Bedeutungen tragen können. Dasselbe gilt für `tauschen` und `wechseln`, wobei beide allgemeiner als die Versionen mit `aus-` sind.

**Wortbeispiele:**

> die Batterien wechseln = die Batterien tauschen
> die Batterien auswechseln = die Batterien austauschen
>
> die Rollen in einer Diskussion wechseln = die Rollen in einer Diskussion tauschen
> die Rollen in einer Diskussion auswechseln = die Rollen in einer Diskussion austauschen
> die Rollen in einer Diskussion vertauschen = die Rollen in einer Diskussion verwechseln

Das letzte Beispiel funktioniert nur unter Missachtung der Konnotation von `verwechseln`.