# Unterschied zwischen "tauschen" und "austauschen"

Tags: synonym

Was ist genau den Unterschied zwischen tauschen und austauschen? Ihre Definitionen sind im Duden sehr ähnlich. Beispiele:

> Die beiden Banden tauschen Gefangene (aus).
>
> Die beiden Modelle tauschen Plätze (aus).

Ich weiß, das Präfix aus- drückt hier aus, dass eines der Objekte keine Rolle/keinen Platz/keine Funktion hat. Aber dies reicht nicht aus, um die Wahl zwischen beiden Verben  in vielen Zusammenhängen zu rechtfertigen.

Comment: Ähnlich zu https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/22499/unterschied-zwischen-tauschen-und-auswechseln/22500#22500

Comment: I guess it is like in English: *change* (wechseln, tauschen) and *exchange* (auswechseln, austauschen) are also very similar.

Comment: Ich glaube das Thema ist extrem breit, um es hier wirklich einfach beantworten zu können, es besteht z.B. ein Unterschied zwischen dem Tauschen und dem Austauschen von Batterien, aber das ist nur einer von vielen Teilaspekten.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unterschied zwischen »tauschen« und »(aus)wechseln«](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/22499/unterschied-zwischen-tauschen-und-auswechseln)

Comment: This is not a duplicate. The mentioned question  explains the meaning of the aus- prefix in "austauschen", but the meaning alone is not enough to justify choosing between "tauschen" and "austauschen" in many contexts. Seemingly this must be learned by heart. I expect an answer that covers most contexts, even if it focused on examples instead of a general rule.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bei *austauschen* wird immer gleiches ausgetauscht: Gefangene gegen Gefangene, Batterien gegen Batterien, etc. "Die Banden tauschen Gefangene" klingt ein bisschen, als ob sie Gefangene gegen Verpflegung, Munition, o.Ä. tauschen.

*austauschen* kann, besonders bei Abstrakte, bedeuten, dass beide geben, ohne zu verlieren: Wenn A und B Erinnerungen **austauschen**, dann haben nachher beide noch ihre eigenen Erinnerungen. Wenn A und B Erinnerungen **tauschen**, dann hat A nachher nur noch Bs Erinnerungen (und zwar alle!), und B nur noch As Erinnerungen (und zwar alle!)

Ohne weiteren Kontext hat *austauschen* eher den Beigeschmack von "Ich geb dir was von meinen, du gibst mir was von deinen", und *tauschen* den von "Ich geb dir meins, du gibst mir deins":

> Wir haben Kleider getauscht

klingt sehr, als ob jeder die Kleider des jeweils anderen angezogen hätte.

> Wir haben Kleider ausgetauscht

klingt eher so, als ob jeder dem anderen eigene Kleider gegeben hat.

Aber in vielen Fällen, wo aus dem Kontext ohnehin klar ist, was genau gemeint ist, wird man beides austauschbar verwenden können.

*Platz tauschen* ist schließlich ein fester Ausdruck, der zweite Satz müsste also heißen:

> Die beiden Models tauschen Platz.

Comment: Ich bin nicht sicher, wenn ich die generelle Unterscheidung zwischen beiden Verben und das Beispiele mit Kleider verstanden habe.  "Ich geb dir was von meinen, du gibst mir was von deinen" = "Ich gebe dir ein Teil von meinem, du gibst mit ein Teil von deinen"? Also "Kleider tauschen" = "swap all our clothes" und "Kleider austauschen" = "swap a subset of our clothes"?

Comment: @AlanEvangelista Yes, and the most natural interpretation for the two is that "Kleider tauschen" = I put on what you're wearing, you put on what I'm wearing, whereas "Kleider austauschen" = We meet up and give each other some of the clothes we have lying around.

Comment: The example with the clothes was a bit confusing. Based on your previous definitions, I initially expected that the meaning of "austauschen" in the example would be "to swap ALL our clothes". however, in fact the usual meaning is  a more specific one: "to swap all the clothes we are wearing now". Now it is completely clear.

Comment: @AlanEvangelista Did you mean that you expected that the meaning of "tauschen" (rather than "austauschen, as you wrote in the comment) would be "to swap ALL our clothes"? Otherwise I fear there might still be some misunderstanding somewhere

Comment: @AlanEvangelista Concerning one of your comments to another question, I think that as far as collectibles are concerned (post stamps, coins, whatever), _tauschen_ will always be the correct word, even though from the general usage you might expect that it would be _austauschen_. I have no idea why.

Comment: Based on the general definition of both verbs you've given before the examples, yes, I *initially* understood that austauschen would mean to swap the entire set of our clothes,  tauschen would mean to swap a subset of our clothes and, most importantly, that the "set of our clothes" would mean the exact same thing in both contexts. As you have already explained, this is not the case. The former is about the clothes *I am wearing*, the latter is about the clothes *I have*. That is hardly deducible from the verbs definitions only and that's what I found kinda confusing in the example.

Comment: thanks for the information about collectibles! it would be nice if you could edit your answer and add this info to it

Answer (score -1):

Die Unterschiede lassen sich schwer allgemein gültig in Worte fassen, deshalb versuche ich es stattdessen, an Beispielen zu verdeutliche.

> Die beiden Banden tauschen Gefangene (aus).

Das entsprechende Nomen liefert meiner Meinung nach einen deutlichen Hinweis: Es gibt keinen *Gefangenentausch*, sondern nur einen *Gefangenen**aus**tausch*. Also können zwei Banden Gefangene nur austauschen, nicht aber tauschen.

Ganz einig sind sich die Deutschen in diesem Fall aber nicht. Während viele deutsche Zeitungen 2017 davon berichten, dass die Ukraine und Russland Gefangene *austauschen* (z.B. [WELT](https://www.welt.de/politik/ausland/article171954457/Ukraine-Rebellen-und-Regierung-tauschen-Gefangene-aus.html), [Zeit](https://www.zeit.de/politik/ausland/2017-12/ukraine-kriegsparteien-gefangene-austausch), [Spiegel](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YTakIGTkbkI), [Tagesspiegel](https://de.reuters.com/article/ukraine-russland-kampfpilotin-idDEKCN0YG19V)...), gibt es auch einige, die den selben Vorgang damit beschreiben, dass Gefangene getauscht werden ([euronews](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YTakIGTkbkI), [Reuters](https://de.reuters.com/article/ukraine-russland-kampfpilotin-idDEKCN0YG19V)).

> Waren, Bücher, Dokumente austauschen

Ähnlich wie die Gefangenen ersetzt man hier Dinge, die man anfassen kann.

> Die beiden Modelle tauschen Plätze (aus).

Beide Modelle ändern ihren Platz. Es findet dabei kein Austausch an greifbaren Gegenständen statt: Der "Platz" ist ein relativ abstrakter Begriff. Laut Duden steckt in "austauschen" auch "wechselseitig übergeben". Einen Platz kann ich nicht wechselseitig übergeben. Deshalb kann man ihn nicht *austauschen*, wohl aber *tauschen*.

Wenn zwei Personen stattdessen ihren (Sitz-)platz austauschen, würde es wohl eher heißen, dass sie sich wechselseitig ihre Stühle geben. Das macht keinen Sinn. Deshalb kann man es so nicht sagen.

> die Wohnung tauschen

Die "Wohnung zu tauschen" ist wieder ein abstrakter Ausdruck. Es heißt, dass zwei Personen in die Wohnung der jeweiligen anderen Person ziehen oder das eine Person in eine neue Wohnung zieht.

Wenn du die Wohnung stattdessen *austauschst*, müsstest du die Wohnung abbauen und eine andere Wohnung aufbauen.

> Grüße mit jemandem tauschen

.. ist ebenfalls abstrakt, da man Grüße nicht greifen kann.

**Aber:**

> Waren, Bücher, Dokumente tauschen

In diesem Fall handelt es sich um Tauschhandel: Du bezahlst eine Ware von mir mit einer Ware von dir. Wir tauschen Waren.

> Briefmarken, Yu-Gi-Oh Karten, Münzen (aus)tauschen

In diesem Fall ist beides erlaubt: Du tauschst etwas *aus*, weil du Gegenstände austauschst. Als Eselsbrücke könntest du es dir in diesem Fall auch als Tauschhandel vorstellen. Deshalb kannst du auch *tauschen* sagen.

> Ringe tauschen

Auf einer Hochzeit möchte das Paar Ringe tauschen, nicht austauschen. Wenn es Ringe austauschen würde, würde es die Ringe abgeben und neue besorgen. Sie möchten sich die Ringe aber gegenseitig geben. Als Eselsbrücke kannst du es dir so vorstellen, dass der Vorgang wieder abstrakt ist: Es geht nicht darum, dem anderen einen Ring zu geben, sondern um das Versprechen der Ehe, das damit verbunden ist. Deshalb *tauscht* das Paar die Ringe, statt sie auszutauschen.

Comment: Definition 2a von "austauschen" lautet "jemandem etwas zukommen lassen und von ihm etwas derselben Art erhalten" und entsprechende Beispiele sind: "Höflichkeiten, Erinnerungen, Gedanken, Meinungen, Informationen austauschen". Deshalb denke ich, dass "austauschen" mit abstrakten Dinge benutzt werden kann. Es scheint mir, dass es keine allgemeine Regel gibt, zwischen den beiden Verben zu wählen, und das Fall von Fall gelernt werden muss.

Comment: @AlanEvangelista mein Ziel war nicht, allgemeine Regeln aufzustellen, ich habe im ersten Satz meines Beitrags explizit darauf hingewiesen, dass das schwierig ist. Stattdessen habe ich versucht, anhand von Beispielen Ansätze für die Sprachpraxis zu liefern und gleichzeitig mit Gegenbeispielen gezeigt, dass diese Ansätze eben nicht universell einsetzbar sind. Ich verstehe nicht ganz, was daran ein -1 rechtfertigt. Wenn du konkrete Verbesserungsvorschläge hast, bin ich gern offen, diese in meinen Beitrag aufzunehmen.

Comment: Zuerst Danke für deine Antwort. Also erscheint es mir verwirrend, in einigen Beispielen die Verwendung eines Wortes A anstelle eines Wortes B zu rechtfertigen, weil A nicht abstrakt verwendet werden kann, wenn A in anderen Beispielen abstrakt verwendet werden kann. Zumindest solltest du einige häufige Fälle explizit erwähnen, in denen deine Argumentation nicht zutrifft. Wenn es jedoch keine allgemeine Regel gibt, die zumindest die meisten Fälle abdeckt, denke ich, dass es besser ist, es klarer zu machen und anhand von Beispielen zu lehren.

Answer (score -2):

Ausführliche Antworten und zahlreiche Beispiele findest du auf https://www.dwds.de/wb/tauschen  sowie  https://www.dwds.de/wb/austauschen.

Comment: Der einzige Unterschied zwischen Duden und DWDS ist, dass DWDS "tauschen" auf Dinge beschränkt. "austauschen" kann immer noch sowohl auf Personen als auch auf Dinge angewendet werden. Im Zusammenhang mit den Dingen (Briefmarken, Münzen, Wohnungen, Produkten, Fernsehsendungen) sehe ich immer noch keinen Unterschied zwischen den beiden Verben.

Comment: @AlanEvangelista: Der [Partnertausch](https://www.sixx.de/tv/partnertausch-wir-retten-unsere-ehe) ist aber nicht auf Dinge beschränkt. ;)